# Entity Framework Async failing, no exception

Tags: entity-framework, async-await

Consider the code below. My foo line returns data. My bar line also returns data. However, if I were to comment out the foo line, then the bar line fails to return anything. It simply crashes the app without throwing an exception. Nor does it log anything in the Event Log.

Any thoughts as to why the Async method fails - only when not preceded by the non-Async?

```
private async Task<bool> MyTest() {
    using(var cntx = new BoomiData.PantherDataContext(pantherConnectionString)) {
try {
    //var foo = cntx.Manifests.FirstOrDefault();
    var bar = await cntx.Manifests.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
}
catch(Exception ex) {
    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
}
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: How are you calling MyTest? If this is a console application or such that doesn't support awaiting, you may need to call `var result = MyTest().GetAwaiter().Result();` rather than `var result = await MyTest();`